# Obtaining position during transition.to in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I was wondering if it was possible to obtain a sprite x and y coordinates during a transition.to animationin using Corona SDK in lua?  If so, how would I go about getting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check it with `enterFrame` listener in Runtime or use a `timer` that triggers continously.

Timer method:

```
local function checkPos_withTimer()
   print(yourObject.x)
   print(yourObject.y)
end
timer.performWithDelay(1,withTimer,-1)
```

---

### or

use enterFrame check:

```
local function checkin_frames()
   print(yourObject.x)
   print(yourObject.y)
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",checkin_frames)
```

Keep coding......... :)

Comment: Yea i researched it a little more and figured a timer loop would be the ideal solution.  i'm fairly new to lua and Corona SDK so I was just wanting to make sure there wasn't a way to do so to save some processor power.  Thank you though this helps though.